OpenSSL HMAC token creation leading to unknown seg fault
Im attempting to add some custom user access tokens to my Mongoose WS and Im generating an HMAC using OpenSSL lib to verify with. I'm using to all-in-one HMAC function provided by OpenSSL. However, *HMAC() continues to generate a segmentation fault:
#include "token.h"

#define TK_SIZE 32
#define HASH_SIZE 32
#define PKEY_PATH "mysecretkey.pem"

int get_pkey(unsigned char **key, size_t *key_len) {
    FILE* pkey_file = fopen(PKEY_PATH, "r");
    if (!pkey_file) return 0;

    fseek(pkey_file, 0, SEEK_END);
    *key_len = ftell(pkey_file);
    fseek(pkey_file, 0, SEEK_SET);

    *key = (unsigned char*) malloc(*key_len);
    if (!(*key)) {
        fclose(pkey_file);
        return 0;
    }

    if (fread(*key, 1, *key_len, pkey_file) != *key_len) {
        free(*key);
        fclose(pkey_file);
        return 0;
    }

    fclose(pkey_file);
    return 1;
}

int get_tk_hash(char** tk_hash) {
    unsigned char tk[TK_SIZE];
    unsigned char hash[HASH_SIZE];
    unsigned char* key = NULL;
    size_t key_len = 0;
    unsigned int hashlen = HASH_SIZE;

    // Get secret key
    if (!get_pkey(&key, &key_len)) goto err;

    // Generate 32-byte token
    if (!gen_32byte_token(tk)) goto err;

    // Generate HMAC hash of token
    if (!HMAC(EVP_sha256(), key, key_len, tk, TK_SIZE, hash, &hashlen)) goto err;

    // Convert token and hash to hexadecimal
    char tk_to_hex[TK_SIZE * 2 + 1];
    uchar_to_hex(tk, TK_SIZE, tk_to_hex);
    char hash_to_hex[HASH_SIZE * 2 + 1];
    uchar_to_hex(hash, HASH_SIZE, hash_to_hex);

    // Combine token+hash, separate with period
    char hex[sizeof(tk_to_hex) + 1 + sizeof(hash_to_hex)] = "";
    strcat(hex, tk_to_hex);
    strcat(hex, ".");
    strcat(hex, hash_to_hex);

    *tk_hash = (char*) malloc(strlen(hex) + 1);
    if (*tk_hash == NULL) goto err;

    strcpy(*tk_hash, hex);
    free(key);  // Free the key after use
    return 1;

err:
    if (key) free(key);
    return 0;
}

int gen_32byte_token(unsigned char* tk) {
    if (RAND_bytes(tk, TK_SIZE) != 1) {
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}


I have verified the key and its length as well as tk and its length. I did try to use backtrace to find the exact spot of the error but to little avail. I think Im missing something in terms of understanding HMACing and OpenSSL.
Any pointers would be helpful. Thank you.

See How do you determine the size of a file in C? fseek()/ftell() to get the size of a file has all kinds of problems.
